# CosmosDb querying in sub-object

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to find accounts with a "extra-storage" premium package for a particular user in my Azure CosmosDb database. Here's what my `Account` object looks like:

```
{
   "id": 123,
   "name": "My Account",
   "members": [
      {
         "id": 333,
         "name": "John Smith"
      },
      {
         "id": 555,
         "name": "Jane Doe"
      }
   ],
   "subscription": {
       "type": "great-value",
       "startDate": "2022-04-21T16:38:00.0000000Z",
       "premiumPackages": [
          {
             "type": "extra-storage",
             "status": "active"
          },
          {
             "type": "video-encoding",
             "status": "cancelled"
          }
       ]
   }
}
```

So, my conditions for the query (in-English) are:

1. Account must contain "John Smith" (id: 333) as a member
2. It must have the "extra-storage" premium package in its `subscription`

I'm not sure if I can have multiple `JOIN`s but here's what I've tried with no results so far:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, s.premiumPackages.status
FROM c JOIN m IN c.members
    JOIN s IN c.subscription
WHERE CONTAINS(m.id, 333)
    AND CONTAINS(s.premiumPackages.type, "extra-storage")
```

Any idea how I can get accounts with "extra-storage" package for "John Smith"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should give you what you are looking for.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, premiumPackages.status
FROM c
JOIN (SELECT VALUE m FROM m IN c.members WHERE m.id = 333)
JOIN (SELECT VALUE s FROM s IN c.subscription.premiumPackages WHERE s.type 
= "extra-storage") AS premiumPackages
```

This blog post on [Understanding how to query arrays in Azure Cosmos DB](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/understanding-how-to-query-arrays-in-azure-cosmos-db/) is helpful to keep bookmarked when trying to write queries for arrays.

PS, `id` on the root in Cosmos DB must be a string so your `"id": 123` should be `"id": "123"`.

Comment: Yes, this works nicely. This answered a few questions I had. Now, I know I can have multiple `JOIN`'s. Also using a `SELECT` for `JOIN`s is not something I was familiar with. This is very helpful indeed. Thank you! And you're correct about `id`s. I actually use `Guid` values but for simplification purposes, I used `int` in my original post. Thanks again. Really appreciate it!